# send email when user registers - AWS Cognito federated Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, federated-identity, amazon-cognito

How can i send an email/trigger a lambda function when a new user registers?

Under "edit identity pool" i only found a sync trigger.
If i understand correctly: This one is triggered every time a user syncs his data...
Is there any way to trigger a lambda function only for the "initial" sync or when a certain dataset is created for the user?

[image]

Edit:
To be more specific: I do create the user via lambdas using the JS SDK. I use developer authentication with my own oauth2 flow. I don't know how to distinguish between a user granting access e.g. via Google the first time from someone doing this the second time. The json with the access code seams the same to me... Maybe I am mistaken.

Also using the `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` call I don't know how to distinguish between an ID that is new to cognito from one cognito already knows.

Edit 2:
To be even more precise:
I am building on this project: https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-boilerplate/blob/master/authentication/lib/storage/usersStorage.js

here is how i do save the User to cognito at the moment.
I do run this code for first time users as well as nth time users. My problem is that i dont know how to distinguish...

```
const saveCognito = (profile) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (profile) {
    cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity({
      IdentityPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
      Logins: {
        // profile.userId = encrypted id of the e.g. google oauth2 id
        [process.env.COGNITO_PROVIDER_NAME]: profile.userId 
      }
    }, (err, dat) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        var list_params = {
          DatasetName: 'user-data', /* dataset name */
          IdentityId: dat.IdentityId, /* cognito id */
          IdentityPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
        };
        cognitosync.listRecords(list_params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err); // an error occurred
          } else {

            var RecordPatches = //[Parts of the i want to write to the user]
            // SyncSessionToken is returned by the cognitosync.listRecords call
            list_params["SyncSessionToken"] = data.SyncSessionToken; 
            list_params["RecordPatches"] = RecordPatches;

            cognitosync.updateRecords(list_params, function(err, update_data) {
              if (err){
                reject(err);
              } else {
                resolve();
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    reject('Invalid profile');
  }
});
```

Comment: I assume the actual users are created not with lambdas?

Comment: @Erndob see my edit/extension to the questions

Comment: To create users you have a lambda that adds them to the pool, it's different from logging in, can't you just trigger the email sending lambda from your registering lambda?

Comment: @Erndob please see my second update and code. Hope this clarifies. Also i hope that this is the way to do it using cognito. I am not 100 percent sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is something which is not currently supported in Cognito out of the box. You are correct in saying that the only built in Cognito Event that will trigger a Lambda Function is the "Sync Trigger" Event. This Sync event is fired every time that a Cognito IdentityId Synchronizes some of their data to the Cognito Sync cloud data store.

This event is unrelated to the creation of a new IdentityId by Cognito Federated Identity.

You could in theory:

- Run a list-identities call on the IdentityPool, before the user logs
  in.
- Login the user. Check whether the IdentityId which has been given to the user is present in the list you retrieved before they logged
  in. This would tell you whether or not the identity that they were
  given existed before this login.
- Based on this information you could
  make a decision whether or not to programatically call the Lambda
  Function from your application.

The setup of the above would be complex, as for security reasons you would need to maintain this service, server-side. The list-identities call requires AWS credentials to call. And I doubt you'd want to include permissions for that call in your IAM policy for unauthenticated users.

Aside from the above there is not much you can do at the moment. 
In order to do this, you would need to setup a DynamoDB table (or some similar low latency datastore) where you could maintain the state of the IdentityId list, and then query this service/store whenever you login a user to compare new logins to the pre-existing list.

If this is critical to your use case I would suggest heading over to AWS Support, and create a case where you can log this as a feature request.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/

Comment: thanks for the answer. Too bad it is not implemented (yet ?). I was testing cognito to use it in a project. It is critical in my workflow but as a student unfortunately i do not have access to premiumsupport... :(.

The only alternative solution to your suggestion i can think of:
If `listRecords` returns an empty-dataset => User us new => Send Email
This should work as i do safe the __ profile__ information gathered from e.g. google for every user. So all my user will have the `user-data` recordset

Comment: That's a good solution too, checking the dataset, to see if it's empty. Then sticking in some data into the records to signify that the user is non-new. Yeah I've been there, I was a student working on this stuff once so I know how it feels :)