# How to get notified (trigger a lambda) when user registers with an authentication provider like fb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

My goal is to create a user in my user table with the data from the fresh facebook auth.
The closest thing I found is within Identity Pool settings:

[image]

But it's not the event I had in mind. I want a trigger only when a new user comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I didn't found such trigger and it looks that there were no changes since. And you don't know on a client side is it a registration or login.

You can only make *workaround* like create a dataset and store some information there (e.g. first_login), based on which you could do your stuff.

There is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229745/send-email-when-user-registers-aws-cognito-federated-identities) you could check.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito supports Lambda triggers that are being engaged in various steps of the authentication flow. You can find more info on this [doc page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html).
The username is included in every lambda trigger input (part of the UserAttributes) check the trigger parameter part of the doc.

Finally, when the user is coming from another provider the user name has a prefix that shows the provider the user signed up with.

If it's Facebook: the username will start with Facebook. For Google the prefix is Google and for Amazon is "LoginWithAmazon". So you can use this information to keep track.

Comment: These Lambda triggers are not being triggered in case of a federated login, unless that federated user was linked to a username/password user.